# How can i reproduce an image out of randomly shuffled pixels?

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHe9Z.jpg)   [my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JOOR.jpg) Hi I am using this python code to generate an shuffle pixel image is there any way to make this process opposite ? for example I give this code output's photo to the program and it reproduce the original photo again.

**I am trying to generate an static style image and reverse it back into the original image and I am open into any other ideas for replacing this code**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

orig = Image.open('lena.jpg')
orig_px = orig.getdata()

orig_px = np.reshape(orig_px, (orig.height * orig.width, 3))
np.random.shuffle(orig_px)

orig_px = np.reshape(orig_px, (orig.height, orig.width, 3))

res = Image.fromarray(orig_px.astype('uint8'))
res.save('out.jpg')
```

Comment: That's the same as asking if you can tell what I started with if I give you the shuffled list `87, 43, 32, 29, 34, 200`.

Comment: If you knew the exact random shuffling algorithm/sequence so you could reverse it then this should be possible. But then it’s not random shuffling…

Comment: It would help if you said what you are actually trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: @balmy so could you help me and give me some hints on how can I use exact shuffle algorithm on my code ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you help me how can I define a manual shuffle algorithm and how can I reverse the whole process ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i am trying to make a selected photo into some noise style photo and then try to reverse the noise style photo back into the original photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, bear in mind that JPEG is lossy - so you will never get back what you write with JPEG - it changes your data! So, use PNG if you want to read back losslessly exactly what you started with.

You can do what you ask like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def shuffleImage(im, seed=42):
    # Get pixels and put in Numpy array for easy shuffling
    pix = np.array(im.getdata())

    # Generate an array of shuffled indices
    # Seed random number generation to ensure same result
    np.random.seed(seed)
    indices = np.random.permutation(len(pix))

    # Shuffle the pixels and recreate image
    shuffled = pix[indices].astype(np.uint8)
 
    return Image.fromarray(shuffled.reshape(im.width,im.height,3))

def unshuffleImage(im, seed=42):

    # Get shuffled pixels in Numpy array
    shuffled = np.array(im.getdata())
    nPix = len(shuffled)

    # Generate unshuffler
    np.random.seed(seed)
    indices = np.random.permutation(nPix)
    unshuffler = np.zeros(nPix, np.uint32)
    unshuffler[indices] = np.arange(nPix)

    unshuffledPix = shuffled[unshuffler].astype(np.uint8)
    return Image.fromarray(unshuffledPix.reshape(im.width,im.height,3))

# Load image and ensure RGB, i.e. not palette image
orig = Image.open('lena.png').convert('RGB')

result = shuffleImage(orig)
result.save('shuffled.png')

unshuffled = unshuffleImage(result)
unshuffled.save('unshuffled.png')
```

Which turns Lena into this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! that was what I exactly wanted

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to do that reliably as far as I know. Theoretically you could brute force it by shuffling the pixels over and over and feeding the result into Amazon Rekognition, but you would end up with a huge AWS bill and probably only something that is approximately the original picture.

Comment: thanks for your help , so let's assume that we shuffle that image manually not randomly in this case is it still impossible to reproduce it ? and if your answer is yes could you please help me how can I shuffle it manually ?

Comment: If you shuffle it in a non-random way it could be reversible.